# ORACLE SQL CASE ERROR FROM KEYWORD

Tags: sql, oracle

Me encuentro buscando soluciones al error que se me presenta al momento de escribir esta query (Soy nuevo en la plataforma, lamento la inapropiada documentación del código):

```
 SELECT  EVALUATION
 CASE 
   WHEN EVALUATION = '1' THEN 'Malo'
   WHEN EVALUATION = '2' THEN 'Regular'
   WHEN EVALUATION = '3' THEN 'OK'
   WHEN EVALUATION = '4' THEN 'Bueno'
   WHEN EVALUATION = '5' THEN 'Excelente'
 ELSE 'No diligenciado' END 
 FROM REGISTRATIONS;
```

Ahora, si bien parece que esta en orden, me sale error `FROM keyword not found where expected`

Tambien intente la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
   EVALUATION
    decode ( EVALUATION, 
                     '1','MALO',
                     '2','REGULAR',
                     '3','OK',
                     '4','BUENO',
                     '5','EXCELENTE',
                     'NO FUE DILIGENCIADO')STATUSTEXT
  FROM REGISTRATIONS;
```

Me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: A `SELECT EVALUATION` le falta una coma, es decir `SELECT EVALUATION,`. Si este es el problema te sugiero que elimines la pregunta o eventualmente terminará cerrada como error tipográfico. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a hacer la query del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT EVALUATION,
(CASE REGISTRATIONS.EVALUATION
    WHEN '1' THEN 'Malo'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'Regular'
    WHEN '3' THEN 'OK'
    WHEN '4' THEN 'Bueno'
    WHEN '5' THEN 'Excelente'
    ELSE 'No diligenciado'
END) 
FROM REGISTRATIONS;
```

Comment: Hola J, gracias por aportar. Sin embargo para que una respuesta sea de buena calidad ha de explicar qué habia mal en el planteamiento de la pregunta y como el codigo que muestras funciona. Mira [answer] para más info y el [tour] para aprnder como funciona este sitio. Un saludo y bienvenido